# What's the android ADB command to click the title of the Settings screen

Tags: android, adb

On android Settings screen, I want first click the "Settings", then go down the menu. I can use

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

or

```
adb shell input swipe x1 y1 x2 y2
```

Is there a simpler way such as using android keycode? something like:

```
adb shell input keyevent key_code
```

I did not find such.

Comment: have you tried KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN, KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER, KEYCODE_ENTER?

Answer (score 4):

Open settings window

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings
```

You can use keycodes for DPAD

```
19 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_UP" 
20 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN" 
21 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT" 
22 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT" 
23 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER"
```

to move down:

```
adb shell input keyevent 20
```

and up:

```
adb shell input keyevent 19
```

to select row:

```
adb shell input keyevent 23
```

It works fine for me (no rooted Samsung Galaxy S3)

Answer (score -1):

This works for me...

adb -s  shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings

adb shell input key event 19 *'DPAD_UP*

adb shell input key event 19              *'for focusing the controls placed on the extreme top.*

***{"adb shell input keyevent 19"  has to be executed two times to focus on the controls placed on the extreme top.}***

adb shell input key event 23 *'inject DPAD_CENTER event to toggle the wifi toggle.*